# animation when i reach a particular div

Tags: jquery, html

I want to have fadeIn effect when I reach Part 1 and Prt 2 section of page. I found a sloution but that will give animation at only one div. I am new to jquery and I have trying to have this animation at both part.

Here is my html code:

```
<div></div>
<h1 id="scroll-to1">PART 1</h1>
<div></div>
<h1 id="scroll-to">PART 2</h1>
```

This is jquery code which I used:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   var hT1 = $('#scroll-to1').offset().top,
       hH1 = $('#scroll-to1').outerHeight(),
       wH1 = $(window).height(),
       wS1 = $(this).scrollTop();
   var hT = $('#scroll-to').offset().top,
       hH = $('#scroll-to').outerHeight(),
       wH = $(window).height(),
       wS = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (wS1 > (hT1+hH1-wH1)){
    console.log('reach');
    $('#scroll-to1').fadeIn(3500);
    $(window).off('scroll')
   }
   if (wS > (hT+hH-wH)){
     console.log('reach');
    $('#scroll-to').fadeIn(3500);
    $(window).off('scroll')
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery Plugin is useful for that.

```
$('.entry').waypoint(function() {
   alert('The element has appeared on the screen.');
});
```

http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/

Comment: I know about the plugin. I don't want to use plugin